# How to save zip file with file name & extension in Safari 8 using jszip?

Tags: javascript, safari, jszip

I want to save `zip` file on client side using `jszip` library.

Here is my code:

```
function zipDownload(){
    var fileName ="test.zip",
        zip = new JSZip(),
        content,
        img,
        data;

    zip.file("hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
    data = zip.generate({type: $.isFunction(window.Blob) ? "blob" : "base64"});
    fileLoader.saveAs(fileName, "application/zip", data);
}
```

It works fine in all modern browsers except Safari 8.

Safari 8 can't save file with file extension.

This is a sample http://jsfiddle.net/uvhy34ar/3/ that shows this issue in action.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same issue. In my case, I was trying to save a file containing XML code with a custom extension (`.cmf`). Safari 8 always appended the `.xml` extension to mine. thus resulting in `myfile.cmf.xls` instead of `myfile.cmf`.

The fix that worked for me was to set the server response's header to

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

and Voliá! -- no extension is added anymore.

Comment: Thank you, cassi.lup! But I don't have a server side, I want to save a file using only client side code. Anyway, thanks for your advice!

Comment: Sergey, if the `octet-stream` tweak wouldn't have worked, my next option would've been to request the file contents through AJAX and then trigger the save operation directly from the cilent. Have you tried that? Since this only happens in Safari, you should be able to use the `FileAPI`. Maybe there's a way for you to combine the fileLoader plugin with FileAPI and trigger a saveAs operation like that.